# Get Values from row when checked checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

I have a table with checkbox like this:

checkbox   id   size    name

checkbox   1    50*50   aaa

checkbox   2    20*20   bbb

At the moment i can count how many check boxes are selected :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            var $checkboxes = $('#addA td input[type="checkbox"]');


            $checkboxes.change(function(){
                var countCheckedCheckboxes = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
                $('#count-checked-checkboxes').text(countCheckedCheckboxes);
                console.log(countCheckedCheckboxes);

            });

        });
```

My question is, when i select for example first checkbox how can i get value of column size?
Also How to increment the values for example, imagine that I select all checkboxes on previous example, i would like to have something like:

```
var $50.50 = 1
var $20.20 = 1
```

Thanks

EDIT:
Table HTML:

```
    <table id="add-a" class="ad dataTable no-footer" style="width: 1500px;" role="grid">
<thead>
  <tr role="row">
<th align="" class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="add-a" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Add?: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 59px;">Add?</th>
<th align="" class="center sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="add-a" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="ID: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 94px;"> ID</th>
<th align="" class="center sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="add-a" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Size: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 247px;">Size</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td align="left" class="sorting_1"><b><p style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="check_7a53936d" name="checkbox[]" value="300x250_zzzzz" class="r1"></p></b></td>
    <td align="left" class="center">1</td>
    <td align="left" class="center">300x250</td>
  </tr><tr role="row" class="even" style="background: navajowhite;">
    <td align="left" class="sorting_1"><b><p style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="check_fd6cb3e4" name="checkbox[]" value="300x250_aaaa" class="r1"></p></b></td>
    <td align="left" class="center">2</td>
    <td align="left" class="center">300x250</td>
  </tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td align="left" class="sorting_1"><b><p style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="check_503dd438" name="checkbox[]" value="300x250_bbbb" class="r1"></p></b></td>
    <td align="left" class="center">3</td>
    <td align="left" class="center">300x250</td>
  </tr><tr role="row" class="even">
    <td align="left" class="sorting_1"><b><p style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="check_d68b36ad" name="checkbox[]" value="300x250_cccc" class="r1"></p></b></td>
    <td align="left" class="center">4</td>
    <td align="left" class="center">300x250</td>
  </tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td align="left" class="sorting_1"><b><p style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="check_dd7ff4ea" name="checkbox[]" value="300x250_dddd" class="r1"></p></b></td>
    <td align="left" class="center">5</td>
    <td align="left" class="center">300x250</td>
  </tr><tr role="row" class="even">
    <td align="left" class="sorting_1"><b><p style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="check_456f96f3" name="checkbox[]" value="300x250_eeee" class="r1"></p></b></td>
    <td align="left" class="center">6</td>
    <td align="left" class="center">300x250</td>
  </tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td align="left" class="sorting_1"><b><p style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="check_09c16d50" name="checkbox[]" value="300x250_ffff" class="r1"></p></b></td>
    <td align="left" class="center">7</td>
    <td align="left" class="center">300x250</td>
  </tr></tbody>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34872884/4763793

Comment: yes, i can get the value @RinoRaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please try this**

```
$checkboxes.change(function(){
    var size= $(this).attr('value').split('_')[0];
});
```

The split() method is used to split a string into an array of substrings, and returns the new array.

**Tip:** If an empty string ("") is used as the separator, the string is split between each character.

**Note:** The split() method does not change the original string.

Comment: hi @Rino Raj, thanks. but with that i got on console 'undefined'

Comment: Can you add the html of the checkbox?

Comment: I made a mistake. Sorry. HTML of the table

Comment: Can you add that along with the question

Comment: Added Rino, I have the size also on checkbox value, so maybe is possible to get from there?

Comment: $(this).parent().parent().parent().next().next().find('td').first().text();

Comment: var size= $(this).attr('value').split('_')[0];

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: size is not defined

Comment: :) At last. I was working on a fiddle for you , to show the demo.

Comment: the only problem i see now, is that I have datatable with pagination, and i only can get sizes from first page, the next pages i can't get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You got a value of attribute using `attr()` and you can get or set a value of  form element using `val()` function.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

                var $checkboxes = $('#addA td input[type="checkbox"]');

        $checkboxes.change(function(){
        var size= $(this).attr('size');  // get size value
        var val = $(this).val(); //  get value
        $(this).val(val++);  // set value increment by 1 

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

i just add class="checkbox" to your checkboxes and now i select every checked checkbox and alert val() of this checkbox.... i hope it will help you

```js
$(".checkbox").click(function(){
  $.each($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked'), function() { 
      alert($(this).val());
  }); 
});
```

```html
    <table id="add-a" class="ad dataTable no-footer" style="width: 1500px;" role="grid">
<thead>
  <tr role="row">
<th align="" class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="add-a" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Add?: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 59px;">Add?</th>
<th align="" class="center sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="add-a" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="ID: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 94px;"> ID</th>
<th align="" class="center sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="add-a" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Size: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 247px;">Size</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td align="left" class="sorting_1"><b><p style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="check_7a53936d" class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="300x250_zzzzz" class="r1"></p></b></td>
    <td align="left" class="center">1</td>
    <td align="left" class="center">300x250</td>
  </tr><tr role="row" class="even" style="background: navajowhite;">
    <td align="left" class="sorting_1"><b><p style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="check_fd6cb3e4" class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="300x250_aaaa" class="r1"></p></b></td>
    <td align="left" class="center">2</td>
    <td align="left" class="center">300x250</td>
  </tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td align="left" class="sorting_1"><b><p style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="check_503dd438" class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="300x250_bbbb" class="r1"></p></b></td>
    <td align="left" class="center">3</td>
    <td align="left" class="center">300x250</td>
  </tr><tr role="row" class="even">
    <td align="left" class="sorting_1"><b><p style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="check_d68b36ad" class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="300x250_cccc" class="r1"></p></b></td>
    <td align="left" class="center">4</td>
    <td align="left" class="center">300x250</td>
  </tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td align="left" class="sorting_1"><b><p style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="check_dd7ff4ea" class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="300x250_dddd" class="r1"></p></b></td>
    <td align="left" class="center">5</td>
    <td align="left" class="center">300x250</td>
  </tr><tr role="row" class="even">
    <td align="left" class="sorting_1"><b><p style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="check_456f96f3" class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="300x250_eeee" class="r1"></p></b></td>
    <td align="left" class="center">6</td>
    <td align="left" class="center">300x250</td>
  </tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td align="left" class="sorting_1"><b><p style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="check_09c16d50" class="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="300x250_ffff" class="r1"></p></b></td>
    <td align="left" class="center">7</td>
    <td align="left" class="center">300x250</td>
  </tr></tbody>
```

Comment: hi @ddd it works, but I still have problem with pagination on datatable, only work on first page

Comment: how does your second page look like? can you show me you code please?

Comment: i dont know what the problem is, i try it on my localhost and it still works.
look at my last post below :)

Answer (score 0):

```
here is my jquerycode:
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".checkbox").click(function(){
    $.each($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked'), function() {
      alert($(this).val());
    });
  });
  $('#add-a').DataTable( {
    "pagingType": "full_numbers"
  });
});
```

Comment: please give me your feedback